# Difference between FILE * "/dev/stdout" and stdout

Tags: c, linux, libc

Let's have a look at this *Hello World* program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Hello, World!");

    const char* sFile = "/dev/stdout"; // or /proc/self/fd/0
    const char* sMode = "w";
    FILE * output = fopen(sFile, sMode);
    //fflush(stdout) /* forces `correct` order */
    putc('!', output); // Use output or stdout from stdio.h

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled using the `output` file descriptor the output is:

```
!Hello, World!
```

when compiled using the `stdout` file descriptor provided by `stdio.h` the output is as expected:

```
Hello, World!!
```

I figure when calling `putc` with the latter, it will print *directly* to the `stdout` and when using the file descriptor on `/dev/stdout` it will open a **pipe** and print into that. I'm not certain though.

The behavior is even more interesting, as it does not overwrite the first character of the 'Hello' but rather pushes itself into the first position of the line buffer in front of the already pushed string.

From a logical point of view this is quiet unexpected.

Can anyone explain what exactly is going on here?

---

I'm using
`cc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2` and a 3.13.0-52 linux kernel compiled w/ gcc 4.8.2

---

**Edit**: I've done an `strace` of both programs, and here is the important part:

The `output` (*fopen("/dev/stdout", "w")*) without `fflush(stdout)` scenario produces:

```
...
open("/dev/stdout", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f62f21e9000
write(3, "!", 1!)                        = 1
write(1, "Hello, World!", 13Hello, World!)           = 13
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

using `fflush(stdout)` produces and enforces correct order:

```
...
open("/dev/stdout", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(1, "Hello, World!", 13Hello, World!)           = 13
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5ad4557000
write(3, "!", 1!)                        = 1
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

The `stdout` (*from stdlib.h*) scenario produces:

```
...
write(1, "Hello, World!!", 14Hello, World!!)          = 14
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

So it seems the `FILE * output = fopen("/dev/stdout")` stream uses a different file descriptor than `stdout` 
Also as it seems `printf` uses `stdout`
Thus in the third scenario the string is assembled before it is pushed on the stream.

Comment: `stdout` is a FILE *, not a file descriptor.  Similarly, `output` is not a file descriptor.  Each has an underlying file descriptor, and if you were to write directly to it you would not see this behavior. (Writing directly to the file descriptor bypasses buffering.)

Comment: The big difference is that each `FILE*` is using its own buffer, unrelated to each other..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both of the streams (`stdout` and `output`) are buffered. Nothing actually gets written until they are flushed. Since you are not explicitly flushing them, nor arranging for them to be automatically flushed, they are only being auto-flushed when they are closed.

You are also not explicitly closing them, so they're being closed (and flushed) by the standard library's `on_exit` hooks. And as William Pursell correctly pointed out, the order in which the buffered I/O streams are closed is not specified.

Look at `fflush(3)`, `fclose(3)`, and `setbuf(3)` manual pages for more information on controlling when and how your output gets flushed.

Comment: A key point is that the order in which they are being closed is unspecified.

Comment: Adding a `fflush(stdout)` before the `putc(...)` in the `output` scenario does not change the behavior.

Comment: It does for me, quite reliably. I would recommend running `strace` on your resulting executable to see the sequence of system calls being produced. This can be quite illuminating anyway to see how the buffered I/O functions interact with the system.

Comment: While officially the order is not specified, on_exit hooks are invoked in the reverse order: ones created later are called first,

Comment: @MrPaulch Your edit has `fflush(output)` , but it should be `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: @nos Good catch! Thank you. Flushing the stdout does resolve the issue!

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/stdout` is not the same as `/proc/self/fd/0` . In fact, if you have not enough priviledges, you won't be able to write to `/dev/stdout` as `/dev/stdout` is not any standard character device in Linux and any attempt to fopen it with the `"w"` option will try to create an actual regular file on that directory. The character device you are looking for is `/dev/tty`

In C language, `stdout` is an initialized global variable of type `FILE *` which points to the standard output file, that is, the file whose descriptor is 1. `stdout` only exists in the C namespace and doesn't relate to any actual file named `"stdout"`

Comment: I don't know what distro you are using but `/dev/stdout` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd/1` which itself is a symbolic link to `/dev/pts/XX` on mine. So they are interchangable. In the end, that was not even the issue :)

Comment: However, it's worth mentioning that neither /dev/stdout, /proc/self/fd, or /dev/fd are standardized, and /dev/tty is.