# Is it possible to see live output of command runned by execute_process?

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm running some time consuming bash script:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "bash" "slow_script.sh"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${INSTALL_SCRIPT_DIR}
    ERROR_VARIABLE ERROR_MESSAGE
    RESULT_VARIABLE ERROR_CODE)
```

and I want to see progress. I tried to show xterm window:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "xterm" "-e" "slow_script.sh"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${INSTALL_SCRIPT_DIR}
    ERROR_VARIABLE ERROR_MESSAGE
    RESULT_VARIABLE ERROR_CODE)
```

It works, but seems ugly.

Is it possible to show script output in CMake output while script is executing?

Comment: Is the script output going to `stdout`?

Comment: @lurker, yes, and to `stderr` as well.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `tee`. You can also reroute `stderr` to, for example, `stdout` with `my command blah blah ... 2>&1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could use some of the standard `/dev` devices as `OUTPUT_FILE`.

The following CMake example worked with a quick test on my Ubuntu machine:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)

project(TestExecuteProcessToStdOut NONE)

execute_process(
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "Test"
    ERROR_VARIABLE ERROR_MESSAGE
    RESULT_VARIABLE ERROR_CODE
    OUTPUT_FILE "/proc/self/fd/0"
)
```

**References**

- [Difference between FILE * "/dev/stdout" and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325508/difference-between-file-dev-stdout-and-stdout)
- [Unix & Linux: echo or print /dev/stdin /dev/stdout /dev/stderr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400849/echo-or-print-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-dev-stderr)

Comment: It works, thanks! BTW this solution, for some reason, has no effect in QtCreator.

Comment: What about windows ? Any idea ?